# datatable row not highligting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Hi I'm trying to get the rows in DataTable to high light when its selected, However the below code isnt working. I can see that the class is being appended to the element but it wont change color.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var table =  $('#table').dataTable({ 

'bProcessing':true, 
 "bJQueryUI": true,
 "bFilter": false,
 "sAjaxSource":'data.php',
    "bAutoWidth": false,
    "aoColumns": [   
            {sWidth: '70px'
                },
                    {
                }

                ]
    }).makeEditable({
   //make editable code

            }],


    });

        $("#table tbody").click(function(event) {
        $(table.fnSettings().aoData).each(function (){
            $(this.nTr).removeClass('row_selected');
        });
        $(event.target.parentNode).addClass('row_selected');
    });



});
```

I'm quite new to javascript so I used the code in datatable as an example for row highlight. Any ideas, thanks.

Comment: If the class is being appended correctly, maybe the problem is with the CSS rules?

Comment: thanks, that was the problem. I had previsoly played around with the css but it didnt work. I just added the rule : .row_selected td{
  background-color: #000000;
} and vola it works

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to add event handlers within the rendering methods of datatables API but this will likely be simpler.

I've used the on() method to bind the event in case you have paging, or future row additions so any rows added in future will also have the handler bound to them

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("#table tbody").on('click','tr',function(event) {
    /* find "selected" class and remove class */                                       
    $('#table tr.row_selected').removeClass('row_selected');
    /* "this" is current row*/
    $(this).addClass('row_selected');
});
```